# How to load env variables from yml file to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I have many environment variables defined in yml file. I use this file locally for configuration. How can I set these variables on my Heroku server without adding my file to repo? My app is built on Ruby on Rails.

Comment: on Heroku, go to personnal app > settings > reveal config vars. Add your config vars here

Comment: You may check this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Check out the [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem. From the github page:

> Simple, Heroku-friendly Rails app configuration using ENV and a single YAML file.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Is there something wrong with this gem?

Comment: I've used the gem for a long time without issue. I don't know why the answer is down-voted. People have their reasons, I suppose.

Comment: @jvillian - I had to test it by myself to ensure it really works :) But I think Wez can be right and you can add something to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to reinvent the wheel… here's a kind of wheel:

```sh
heroku config:set $(cat config/application.yml | grep "^[^\#\ ].*\:\ .*$" | sed 's/\:\ /=/g' | tr "\n" " ")
```

It parses top-level keys of a [*Figaro*](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) YAML file.

**Update:**

You actually can use *Figaro*'s `heroku:set` to reach the same result:

```
$ figaro help heroku:set
Usage:
  figaro heroku:set

Options:
  -a, [--app=APP]                  # Specify a Heroku app
  -e, [--environment=ENVIRONMENT]  # Specify an application environment
  -p, [--path=PATH]                # Specify a configuration file path
                                   # Default: config/application.yml
  -r, [--remote=REMOTE]            # Specify a Heroku git remote

Send Figaro configuration to Heroku
```